# Failed to login using php

Tags: php, codeigniter, passwords

I am using PHP CodeIgniter framework.
Here is the login.php controller.

```
 public function index()
        {
            if($this->input->post('login') == 1)
            {
                $user = new Users_model();
                $user->email = $this->input->post('email');

                $user->password = $this->input->post('password');

                $user->user_role = $this->input->post('user_role');
                $results = $this->usermodel->login($user);

                if(count($results)>0)
                {
                    if(is_array($results) || is_object($results))
                    {
                        foreach($results as $row)
                        {
                            $session_array = array(
                                "id" => $row['id'],
                                "username" => $row['username'],
                                "email" => $row['email'],
                                "password" => $row['password'],
                                "image" => $row['image'],
                                "description" => $row['description'],
                                "account_status" => $row['account_status'],
                                "user_role" => $row['user_role']
                                );
                            $this->session->set_userdata($session_array);
                            $url = base_url() . "home?login=success"; 
                            redirect($url, "refresh"); 
                        }
                    }   
                }else{
                    $url = base_url() . "login?login=failed"; 
                    redirect($url, "refresh"); 
                }
            }else{
                $this->load->view('login-page');
            }
        }
```

Here is the Users_model.php in model.

```
function login($user){
      $conditions = array(
       "email" => $user->email, 
        // "password" => $user->password,
       "user_role" => $user->user_role,
       "account_status" => 1,
       );
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('users');
      $this->db->where($conditions);
      $rs= $this->db->get();

      if(!empty($rs)){
          $result_array = $rs->row_array();
          if(password_verify($user->password,$result_array['password'])){
            return $result_array;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is the password_hash and password_verify correctly?
And below is the error code:

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'id'

Filename: controllers/Login.php

Line Number: 38

and also other string in the session_array

Comment: According to the error message, your `$row` variable is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the foreach loop and everything is fine

```
public function index()
{
    if($this->input->post('login') == 1)
    {
        $user = new Users_model();
        $user->email = $this->input->post('email');

        $user->password = $this->input->post('password');

        $user->user_role = $this->input->post('user_role');
        $results = $this->usermodel->login($user);

        if(count($results)>0)
        {
            if(is_array($results) || is_object($results))
            {
                $session_array = array(
                    "id" => $results['id'],
                    "username" => $results['username'],
                    "email" => $results['email'],
                    "password" => $results['password'],
                    "image" => $results['image'],
                    "description" => $results['description'],
                    "account_status" => $results['account_status'],
                    "user_role" => $results['user_role']
                    );
                $this->session->set_userdata($session_array);
                $url = base_url() . "home?login=success"; 
                   redirect($url, "refresh"); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $url = base_url() . "login?login=failed"; 
            redirect($url, "refresh"); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('login-page');
    }
}
```